# How to limit find_package() search to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH by default?

Tags: cmake

I want to modularize my project and use `find_package` to control 3rdparty inclusions and i also have a strict requirement to control all my packages. I don't want cmake to include something on the side and debug what is going on, i need to limit its search path to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.
The single explicit approach i found is `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` in `find_package` calls but i don't want to repeat these arguments over and over again. Is there a variable that can control it for me? I found a family of variables `CMAKE_FIND_USE_*_PATH` but there is no clear documentation on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure) describes the algorithm of constructing installation prefixes. By following that algorithm it should be easy to collect all `CMAKE_FIND_USE_*_PATH` variables, setting which to FALSE will disable corresponding prefixes:

1. Search paths specified in the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake and environment variables could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` variable.
2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific cache variables could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH` variable.
3. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` variable.
4. Search paths specified by the HINTS option cannot be disabled.
5. Search the standard system environment variables could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` variable.
6. Search paths stored in the CMake User Package Registry could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` variable.
7. Search cmake variables defined in the Platform files for the current system could be omitted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` variable.
8. Search paths stored in the CMake System Package Registry could be omitted by setting  `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` variable.
9. Search paths specified by the PATHS option cannot be disabled.

In total, setting

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY FALSE)
```

is equivalent to NO_DEFAULT_PATH option in every `find_package` call.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to modify some standard behavior of the command you might use functions or macros to hide some details. In this case you need a macro which might look like this:

```
macro(find_package_restricted)
    find_package(${ARGN} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
endmacro()
```

And you use it just like you would use `find_package`:

```
find_package_restricted(Boost REQUIRED)
```